# wkhtmltopdf - How to use spaces in arguments?

Tags: unix, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using **wkhtmltopdf** with local files. I've noticed that it doens't work with space in input/output filenames.

```
wkhtmltopdf --footer-left reports --footer-right [page]/[toPage] -O landscape report.html report.pdf
```

Here is a sample which gets "report.html" file, and converts to a PDF called "report.pdf", enabling a footer with a label written "reports" with the number of current and total pages. Works fine.

---

But now I need to set a string with spaces in the footer label.
I've tried different ways to do it, like using quotes, double-quotes, encoding the space, etc, but not seems to work.

Something like this:

```
wkhtmltopdf --footer-left "Shell - January Report" --footer-right [page]/[toPage] -O landscape /var/shell_report_15_01.html /var/reports/shell_report_15_01.pdf
```

The argument "Shell - January Report" isn't recognized, seems like the quotes are ignored and these spaces are used as argument separators.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you have spaces in the command? Are the underscores spaces, and did you try  `khtmltopdf --footer-left " NICE FOOTER LABEL" --footer-right [page]/[toPage] -O landscape " INPUT FILENAME.HTML" " OUTPUT FILENAME.PDF"`

Comment: @WalterA - Improved my question

Comment: Perhaps try single quotes like `--header-right='[page]/[toPage]'` and try the footer-left without a `-`: `wkhtmltopdf --footer-left 'Shell = January Report' --footer-right '[page]/[toPage]' -O landscape /var/shell_report_15_01.html /var/reports/shell_report_15_01.pdf`

Comment: I suggest to write the command in a script file and then execute that with `bash -x file` or similar, adding the output you get to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, but weirdly enough, if you double the spaces, it works.

Comment: that's it? you should update you answer with reference.